# Indexpath.row returning the row being searched not the actual row PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, parse-platform

Okay so I have a PFQueryTableViewController that pulls data from Parse and then you can search it and select a row. If you just select a row it works fine but if you search and then click on it it returns the "first" row in ALL the data not the row that was clicked. Everything worked fine and I never changed the code but I put the tableviewcontroller in a container and thats why it happened. Seeing the issue I removed it from the container but the problem persisted! I don't know what to do! Here is my code

```
#import "AllDataTableViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface AllDataTableViewController ()  <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate> {

}
@end

@implementation AllDataTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController


@synthesize searchBar;
@synthesize searchController;
@synthesize searchResults;

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.delegate = self;

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"popAgain"] isEqualToString:@"true"])
    {

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        NSString *popAgain = @"false";
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:popAgain forKey:@"popAgain"];

    }
}




- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"TruthIsData";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"truthIsName";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;




            }
    return self;

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (tableView == self.tableView) {

        return self.objects.count;
        NSLog(self.objects);
        NSLog(@"objects");

    } else {
        return self.searchResults.count;

    }

}




-(void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TruthIsData"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        NSArray *results = [NSArray arrayWithArray:objects];

        NSLog(@"%@", results);
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)results.count);
        NSLog(@"results^");


        [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:results];

        NSPredicate *searchPredicate =
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.truthIsName contains[c] %@",searchTerm];
        searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate]];
         [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];

        NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)searchResults.count);
        NSLog(@"search results^");


    }];

}






- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    return query;
    [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {


        cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"truthIsName"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"User: %@", [object objectForKey:@"username"]];

    }
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {


        PFObject* object = self.searchResults[indexPath.row];

        //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"truthIsName"];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"User: %@", [object objectForKey:@"username"]];
    }




    return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    PFObject *obj = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    NSString *quickId = obj.objectId;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:quickId forKey:@"selectedTI"];
    //NSLog(quickId);


   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"selectedRequest" sender:self];


}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self filterResults:searchString];
    return YES;
}



@end
```

I have tried adding this to the view did appear but it didn't help

```
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath you also need to check to see if the tableview is the search table:

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

PFObject* object = self.searchResults[indexPath.row];
}
```

Then do what you need to do with the object...